# Changing values to NaN in column if greater than x

Tags: r, nan

R beginner here.

The data from a relative humidity sensor malfunctioned and produced values over 100 and need to converted into NaNs. Any help is appreciated! Should I use ifelse?

This code  hive1.1[hive1.1$int_h > 100] <- NaN produces this error:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, hive2.1$int_h > 100, value = NaN) : 
  missing values are not allowed in subscripted assignments of data frames

Comment: Use `NA` instead of `NaN`.  If that doesn't fix it, give us a bit of your data and the command you are using.  Use `dput(head(your_object))` and paste it into the question.

Comment: `NaN` is 'not a number' and is usually reserved for undefined return values though it is a little more complicated than that.  `NA` simply means 'not available' i.e. no number.

Comment: Apparently you didn't read the reproducible example link I left on [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052543/how-to-convert-0s-to-nans-in-certain-columns-of-dataframe-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

You need to focus your assignment better:

```
 hive1.1[hive1.1$int_h > 100, "int_h"] <- NaN
```

Or:

```
  is.na(hive1.1[ , 'int_h"])  <- hive1.1$int_h > 100
```

Your code was not limiting the assignment to the column of interest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still guessing a bit about your data, but maybe this:

```
hive1.1$int_h <- ifelse(hive1.1$int_h > 100, NA, hive1.1$int_h)
```

In words, check if the value is > 100, if so, replace it with `NA`, it not, leave it alone (or, more strictly, replace it with itself).  See `?ifelse`.  `ifelse` is vectorized so it operates on each value in sequence.